# Can I put a Blu-Ray burner in a USB DVD enclosure?

Tags: dvd, blu-ray, enclosures

The 5.25" DVD burner in my old USB enclosure is going out, and I'm wondering if it would work to put a Blu-Ray burner in it, or if I should stick with a replacement DVD burner.

Is there any difference in how the USB enclosure will interact with a DVD vs a Blu-Ray drive?

Comment: You would be better to get a USB Blu Ray burner to make sure the device will work properly and that it comes with the necessary drivers.

Comment: Can't think of any reason it won't work. It's still just (S)ATA to USB.

Comment: As long as its not too old of an enclosure, really old ones are IDE not Sata.

Comment: I'm just asking since I couldn't find this question anywhere on the internet. Yes this particular enclosure is SATA. My other thought was to contact a Blu-Ray manufacturer to see what they say.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the USB enclosure can deliver adequate power and the USB standard it supports is fast enough to keep up with the writing, this should work fine.

There is no difference to how a USB enclosure will interact with a DVD vs a Blu-Ray drive that is of concern.